# Display only part of table row

Tags: html, css

Can some one explain how to add row to table in html (tr)
but with only part of cells? The "hard" point of the question is that
the demand is that the un visible part - (two empty cells is the example) will be with the same settings of the **table** - same BG color, but without border lines

Thanks 
[image: example]

**UPDATE:**
You helped very much - but: what if we need now that un visibile cells will have the BG color of the general page, **not table BG** ?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's this cool property that people forget about called [empty-cells](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/empty-cells)
Use it!

Edit: I just saw that you edited your picture that includes background on empty cells. In that case you can use [`:empty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty) selector to remove border from empty cells.

**Using :empty example:**

```css
td {
  border : 1px solid black;
  background : green;
}

td:empty {
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Initial example:**

```css
   body {
  background: blue;
}

td {
  background: white;
  border : 1px solid black;
  empty-cells: hide;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

You would need to change the `border-color` and `background-color` using `:empty` selector or using JavaScript

**Update:** Using `:empty` selector. Thanks to @Paran0a

```css
body {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  background-color: palegreen;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}
td:empty {
  border-color: #dddddd;
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>13</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>21</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```